# How to isolate methods in Ruby - multiprocessing question

Tags: ruby, windows, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have 3 methods that do something on the file system but each method changes current directory and I can't use Threading for those since it uses same ruby process and I have racing condition. I found Process.spawn (can't use fork on windows) might be solution but I don't know how to spawn 3 process and call method in each of those.

I tried following as a test, but didn't work

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def something
  puts 'printaj'
end

def nextsomething
  puts 'vici'
end


pid1 = Process.spawn(something)
pid2 = Process.spawn(nextsomething)
Process.wait pid1
Process.wait pid2
puts 'both finished'
```

Comment: Please see the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) how `spawn` is defined: It creates a child process, and you pass it as parameter the command line to be executed. You can also pass parameters to this new process, to tell it what exactly to execute.

Comment: Yes, but I need to run methods that should be isolated. So I am looking a way how to do it.

Comment: Re, "...each method changes current directory..." That's ugly, and for more than one reason. Why not re-write the methods so that they do not _need_ to change the process's CWD?

Comment: @opti2k4 : Inside the processes, you can run any methods you want, and methods inside a **process** are always executed isolated from methods in other pocesses.

Comment: Our ruby scripts are used for building solution from source. So we have for example, build angular, build webpack steps (methods) and they all work in own directory within source. It is possible to run those processes separately but with threads I have racing condition as they are not isolated so one method reports it's missing source files because other changed source dir.

Answer (score 0):

How about threads and mutex?

```
semaphore = Mutex.new

a = Thread.new {
  semaphore.synchronize {
    # do something on the file system
  }
}

b = Thread.new {
  semaphore.synchronize {
    # do something on the file system
  }
}
```

With this code you will run only one operation on file system in the same time.
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Mutex.html

Comment: Are you sure? If I have under a `chdir c:\, touch fileą, cat filea` and under b `chir e:\, touch fileb, cat fileb` there won't be racing condition and thread from a won't repot not found? I tried with threading without mutex and it didn't work, that was my problem.

Comment: @sig : This is using **threds**, which is of course reasonable, but not what the OP asked for. He explicitly says that he doesn't want to use threading, but separate **processes**. That's why his approach of using `spawn` would basically do what he wants, if he just had called these functions correctly. That having separate processes for this task is maybe not the best idea, is a different question.